# Android: Add View within ViewPager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I'm using a `ViewPager` and a `PagerTitleStrip` to display several Fragments.

What I want is, to add a `TextView` **within** the ViewPager. This TextView should be displayed on Top of every Fragment and should therefore act as kind of a template. The `TextView` should appear between the `PagerTitleStrip` and the `Fragments`.

`MyLayout.xml` currently looks like this:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/projectDetailsPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ProjectDetailsFragment" >

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top" />

 </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

what I tried without success is this:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/projectDetailsPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ProjectDetailsFragment" >

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="DUMMY" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Unfortunatly the TextView doesn't show up. Any idea why?

Comment: *... add a TextView within the ViewPager ...* - can't you simple stack the `ViewPager` and the `TextView` in a `RelativeLayout` or `FrameLayout`so the `TextView` will always be on top? Or what exactly does within mean?

Comment: The `ViewPager`loads severeal Fragments, while every `Fragment` fills the whole site. So, if I'd stack the `ViewPager` and the `TextView`, the `TextView` would never be shown. 

I could attach the `TextView` to the `Fragment` to achieve the same result, but then I would have to add the `TextView` to every single `Fragment`. That's why I want to attach the `TextView` only once to the `ViewPager`.